# Minecraft Forge Gradle with VSCode

Tags: gradle, visual-studio-code, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to create a Minecraft Mod using VSCode as this is my main editor for school, but when I try to run the command gradlew genVSCodeRun I get the follwoing output that says successful, but also "Could not resolve: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3".  When I then run gradlew build, the following it output:

```
Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/eabla/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.15/forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/eabla/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.15/forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.jar
    - https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3/forge-1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.pom
    - https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3/forge-1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.jar
    - https://libraries.minecraft.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3/forge-1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.jar
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3/forge-1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3/forge-1.14.3.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20200119-1.14.3.jar
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 40s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Any idea what this could be? I have done a fresh install of java JDK and JRE as well as a fresh install of the Forge MDK.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qmNzUvyV - build.gradle
Not sure where to find settings.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Your Forge Library is missing. Run the command `gradlew eclipse` after navigating into your project directory. It may take some time but it will surely fix it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the JDK (java development kit https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) installed not just the JRE

Comment: As gradle is running, this proves that the person has a JDK installed